# Creating dynamic delete button for a dictionary using python dash?

Tags: python, plotly-dash

I have a dash app where a user inputs dates with a name attached and this is appended to a dictionary.
Firstly the dictionary is rendered:

```
# Create dictionary that will be updated using 'update_dictionary' functions 
def render_dictionary(dictionary, dictionary_id):
    entries = []
    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        delete_button_id = {'type': 'delete-button', 'index': key}
        entries.append(html.Div([f"{key}: {value}", dbc.Button('Delete', id = delete_button_id, className = 'delete-button')]))
    return entries
```

Each entry is created with a delete button next to it. Then the dictionary is updated with the date and name when the user inputs the data and presses a button.

```
dcc.Dropdown(
    id="year-dropdown-GMT",
    options=[
    {"label": str(year), "value": year}
    for year in range(2018, 2024)
    ],
    value = 2023,
    className="dropDown",
),

dcc.Dropdown(
    id="month-dropdown-GMT",
    options=[
    {"label": "January", "value": 1},
    {"label": "February", "value": 2},
    {"label": "March", "value": 3},
    {"label": "April", "value": 4},
    {"label": "May", "value": 5},
    {"label": "June", "value": 6},
    {"label": "July", "value": 7},
    {"label": "August", "value": 8},
    {"label": "September", "value": 9},
    {"label": "October", "value": 10},
    {"label": "November", "value": 11},
    {"label": "December", "value": 12},
    ],
    value=1,
    className="dropDown",
),

dcc.Dropdown(
    id="day-number-dropdown-GMT",
    value=1,
    className="dropDown",
    ),  # Default to the first day


dcc.Input(
    id="name-input-GMT",
    type="text",
    placeholder="Enter name...",
    spellCheck = True,
    className="mb-3",
),
dbc.Button(
    "Add to Typical Day List",
    id="add-similar-event-button-GMT",
    className="button",
    ),
html.Div(
id="similar-event-dictionary-GMT", 
className="dictionaries"
),

similar_event_dictionary_GMT = {}

@callback(
    Output("similar-event-dictionary-GMT", "children"),
    Input("add-similar-event-button-GMT", "n_clicks"),
    Input({'type': 'delete-button', 'index': ALL}, "n_clicks"), 
    State("year-dropdown-GMT", "value"),
    State("month-dropdown-GMT", "value"),
    State("day-number-dropdown-GMT", "value"),
    State("name-input-GMT", "value"),
    prevent_intial_call = True,   
)

def update_similar_event_dictionary_GMT(add_clicks, delete_clicks, year, month, day, name):
        
        if add_clicks and name and year and month and day:
            date = f"{year}-{month:02d}-{day:02d}"
            similar_event_dictionary_GMT[date] = name 
        
        if delete_clicks:
            keys_to_delete = [str(index) for index, click in enumerate(delete_clicks) if click]
            for key in keys_to_delete:
                similar_event_dictionary_GMT.pop(key, None)

                
        print(similar_event_dictionary_GMT)
        return render_dictionary(similar_event_dictionary_GMT, "similar-event-dictionary-GMT")
```

When the delete button is pressed, nothing happens. By that I mean the dictionary doesn't append or remove any entries. The buttons callback is being triggered as when it is pressed the print statement for the dictionary is triggered.

Instead of `similar_event_dictionary_GMT.pop(key, None)`, I have also tried `del similar_event_dictionary_GMT[key]`. The same result occurs for both.

I want to be able to remove the items in any order, so whichever delete entry button is pressed that corresponding entry will be deleted.

Any suggestions? I have been unable to find similar queries across the internet.

Any more snippets or explanation can be given - I am new to Stack Overflow, please go easy.

Comment: Could you provide a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), (ie. with the relevant part of the layout) ?

Comment: @EricLavault I have added the relevant parts of the layout to the original post, thank you!

Comment: Some ids in the layout don't match those in the callbacks. Assuming those ids match (ie. "year-typical-dropdown-GMT" == "year-dropdown-GMT" and "add-typical-day-button-GMT" == "add-similar-event-button-GMT"), the issue comes from the fact you are using a dictionary where you should use a list of dictionary (or a dict where the keys are numerical indices, which amounts to using a list) : `similar_event_dictionary_GMT[date] = name` the dict is keyed by date where you would need an index to be matched later with that index of the delete-button to make `similar_event_dictionary_GMT.pop(key)` work.

Comment: The ids not matching was my mistake I have a fair few dropdowns in the layout (I have updated the post). Thank you for your suggestion, I will try to implement it.